How to get file download progress in the client side using NanoHttpd android?
I am trying to get the file transfer progress in the client side of the http server I have built using NanoHttpd. But the issue is, after reading the data from the iputStream, there is a socketTimeOutException. How to get rid of it?
Here is my reference code:
class NanoHttpServer(private val activity: AndroidIosFileShareActivity, port: Int) : NanoHTTPD(port) {
override fun serve(session: IHTTPSession): Response {
    val uri = session.uri
    Log.d(TAG, "Session uri: $uri")
    return try {
        when {
            session.method == Method.GET && session.uri == "/exchange-ip" -> {
                handleIpExchange(session)
            }
            session.method == Method.POST && session.uri == "/upload" -> {
                postUpload2(session)
            }
            else -> {
                newFixedLengthResponse(Response.Status.METHOD_NOT_ALLOWED, MIME_PLAINTEXT, "Only POST and GET methods are allowed")
            }
        }
    } catch (e: Exception) {
        e.printStackTrace()
        newFixedLengthResponse(Response.Status.INTERNAL_ERROR, MIME_PLAINTEXT, "Error during upload: ${e.message}")
    }


}

// Handle IP exchange for the GET /exchange-ip endpoint
private fun handleIpExchange(session: IHTTPSession): Response {
    val clientIp = session.remoteIpAddress
    val serverIp = getServerIpAddress() // Custom method to get server IP (or hardcode)

    Log.d(TAG, "Client IP: $clientIp, Server IP: $serverIp")

    CoroutineScope(Dispatchers.Main).launch {
        activity.toggleVisibility(isDeviceConnected = true)
    }


    val ipResponseJson = """
        {
            "client_ip": "$clientIp",
            "server_ip": "$serverIp"
        }
    """.trimIndent()

    return newFixedLengthResponse(Response.Status.OK, "application/json", ipResponseJson)
}


private fun getServerIpAddress(): String? {
    return InternetUtil.getLocalIpAddress() // Replace with actual method to get IP address dynamically
}

private fun postUpload2(session: IHTTPSession): Response {
    println("Received HTTP POST with upload body...")

    // Check if the content type is multipart/form-data
    val contentType = session.headers["content-type"]
    if (contentType == null || !contentType.contains("multipart/form-data")) {
        return newFixedLengthResponse(Response.Status.BAD_REQUEST, "application/json", "{\"error\": \"Invalid content type\"}")
    }

    // Get the content length for progress tracking
    val contentLength = session.headers["content-length"]?.toLongOrNull() ?: 0L
    if (contentLength == 0L) {
        return newFixedLengthResponse(Response.Status.BAD_REQUEST, "application/json", "{\"error\": \"Invalid content length\"}")
    }

    // Create a buffer for reading chunks of the input stream
    val bufferSize = 8192
    val buffer = ByteArray(bufferSize)
    var bytesRead: Int
    var totalBytesRead = 0L

    try {
        // Extract the input stream from the session
        val inputStream = session.inputStream
        val tempFile = File(activity.cacheDir, "uploaded_temp_file")

        // Open output stream to write to a temporary file
        tempFile.outputStream().buffered().use { outputStream ->
            // Read the input stream in chunks and write to the file
            while (inputStream.read(buffer).also { bytesRead = it } != -1) {
                outputStream.write(buffer, 0, bytesRead)
                totalBytesRead += bytesRead

                // Calculate the progress percentage
                val progress = (totalBytesRead * 100 / contentLength).toInt()
                Log.d(TAG, "Upload progress: $progress%")
            }
            inputStream.close()
            outputStream.flush()
            return newFixedLengthResponse(Response.Status.OK, "application/json", "{\"message\": \"File uploaded successfully\", \"file\": \"\"}")
        }
    } catch (e: IOException) {
        e.printStackTrace()
        return newFixedLengthResponse(Response.Status.INTERNAL_ERROR, "application/json", "{\"error\": \"Failed to parse multipart data\"}")
    }
}

companion object {
    private const val TAG = "NanoHttpServer"
}

}
The warning I get after the successful file transfer is:
java.net.SocketTimeoutException: Read timed out
